# How to dynamically add content from one div to another onClick with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How do I add the content from `iteminitial` to `item` each time I click the `additem` button? I don't get why my appendChild doesn't work.

See plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/Z223520OyRfv9XyzcNTu

html:

```
    <div id="iteminitial">      
    <div class="row" style="padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0.5em">
          <div class="col-sm-6" >
               <input class="form-control" type="text" name="number[]">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6" >
               <input class="form-control" type="text" name="period[]">                   
          </div>            
    </div>
    </div>


    <div id="item">     

    </div>


    <div class="row" style="padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0.5em">                  
          <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Add item" onClick="additem();">
    </div>
```

js:

```
function additem(){

      var newitem          = document.getElementById('item');
      var initialitem      = document.getElementById('iteminitial');

      newitem.appendChild(initialitem);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works nicely, but it's just moving the `initialitem` into `item`. What you need to do is clone the `initialitem` and then add it to `item`. Like this: https://plnkr.co/edit/Z4l8jmdEqsrBzbyyIOHj?p=preview

```
function additem(){
    var newitem = document.getElementById('item');
    var initialitem_clone = document.getElementById('iteminitial').cloneNode(true);
    console.log(newitem)
    newitem.appendChild(initialitem_clone);
}
```

Comment: do NOT forget the `initialitem_clone.id = "newid";` https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#adef-id - still holds true even with html5 https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/global-attributes.html#the-id-attribute